# Is it okay to wear this jersey with the Stack Overflow logo for personal use?

Tags: discussion, logo

I have this jersey that I got online. Is it okay to wear it for personal use?

[image: Stack Overflow Shirt]

Comment: No, you're going to have to wear it professionally. ;p

Comment: Why not dude, are you ashamed of something that makes you believe you can't wear it proudly?? Especially if it makes your toy hot, wear it as often you can (pro tip: never wash!).

Comment: ahaha I mean the logo and all the copyright stuff

Comment: May be, you're officially demanded to put a current rep sticky post it along :-P ...

Comment: Did you receive it from an official source, or was it from some other third party?  Keep in mind, Stack Exchange ran a shop for a few years (and I am genuinely kicking myself hard every waking moment for not getting a hoodie while it was open...).

Comment: @Makoto You are aware it's pretty easy to make one your own?? Or is it the kick to have gotten it from that _official shop_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  That *may* be true, but I'd really rather avoid the hot water.

Comment: @Makoto _"hot water"_ as mentioned put a post it with your current rep along ;-P ...

Comment: @BilltheLizard or enthusiastically...

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think copyright only matters as long as you're not selling it and logos are not under copyright.. I don't think I have ever heard a company suing an individual who made their own shirt. It might be frowned upon if you bought from a third party that is not associated with the Stack Network in any way.

Comment: I think the only good question here is "Where can I get one?"

Comment: "... *the United States hasn’t drawn the borders of its lawful personal use zone by statute. Determining the circumstances under which personal use of copyrighted works will be deemed lawful is essentially a matter of inference and analogy, and differently striped copyright lawyers will differ vehemently on whether a particular personal use is lawful or infringing.*" - http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jdlitman/papers/LawfulPersonalUse.pdf

Comment: I don't think it's wrong to wear it or even buy it, but I think the supplier *could* be in tepid water if they were pursued. Most design-your-own sites tend to ask that you have permission to use any images you upload.

Comment: The problem here is not necessarily copyright, but trademark, but in either case, they are not mitigated by "personal use" or whether or not you make any money on it. You might be able to get away with it under ["functional use"](https://www.legalzoom.com/articles/when-is-unauthorized-use-not-trademark-infringement), but IANAL.

Comment: Yeah trademark is the main issue. The really annoying thing about trademark law is that companies can _lose_ their rights to a trademark if they are seen to be failing to "defend" it. As I understand it, this actually means that by coming and asking the question on here, you are potentially putting stackoverflow in the position of needing to say "no" to you, even if they don't really mind. It can be better to just not ask the question.

Comment: Member for six days and have already purchased some merchandise. Asking a question which reveals to many people what they otherwise would never have known. Sounds a bit too much like clever marketing.

Comment: this jersey is not authentic: it lacks downvote button

Answer (score 10):

Did you learn nothing from the teachings of [Admiral Hopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper)?

If you must ask, then the answer can be found [in our trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

Comment: Maybe I'm dense, but these statements seem to imply contradictory answers. Hopper's famous quote, from the linked Wikipedia article, is "[Y]oung people...come to me, you know, and say 'Do you think we can do this?' I say, 'Try it.' And I back 'em up." Whereas the trademark guidelines basically say "no way, Jose."

Comment: Wrong quote, @cody.

Comment: @CodyGray ["It's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is okay for you to use your jersey.

Comment: So you'd say "Just Do It", Just Do It?

Comment: Precisely @Bart

Answer (score -8):

If it's an officially licenses jersey, your fine. If not *remember*...

Any registered trade mark used with out permission can be taking to court if property holders feel that said use (a) compete and/or (b) confuse with original logo.

That being said, personal use usually falls into an "informal use"; which, can be argued that such use falls under "fair use". I'm no lawyer, but if you draw a logo on a t-shirt, and where it around the house -- your fine. Bearing said logo at place of business/trade would be different.

- [*"When is Unauthorized Use Not Trademark Infringement?"*](https://www.legalzoom.com/articles/when-is-unauthorized-use-not-trademark-infringement)
- [*"When You Need Permission to Use Trademarks"*](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/when-you-need-permission-use-trademarks.html)

Answer (score -10):

I'm pretty sure you should be fine unless you're producing and selling them online. For example if I produced a Sci-fi game called Halo and the main character was called MasterChief and I sold it online for personal gain - I would then be in trouble. 
Even if I'm wrong Stack Overflow probably wouldn't bother coming after you, they'd probably go for the person who is producing the sweatshirt.